# Cannot parse a valid time in Go

Tags: datetime, go, parsing, time

I'm trying to parse a timestamp of the format:

```
2021-03-31T13:38:14
```

So I use the layout format of: `2006-02-15T15:04:05`

For some reason all of my datetime objects are parsed correctly except `2021-03-31T13:38:14` and `2021-03-29T14:21:41`. I get an error saying:

> parsing time "2021-03-31T13:38:14": hour out of range

Why is this happening? When the hour is not out of range?

Here's the code:

```
const DateFormat = "2006-02-15T15:04:05"
var toParse = "2021-03-31T13:38:14"
submittedAt, err := time.Parse(DateFormat, toParse)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `2006-01-02` in `DateFormat`?

Comment: should work fine with correct month and day: https://play.golang.org/p/BNtT5udHDQ7

Comment: Oh wow I didnt notice that was wrong. Thank you,.

Comment: if the input had a UTC offset as well, you could have used RFC3339 from the [constants](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Answer (score 2):

The format for day of the month is 02 and month is 01. So your layout format should be `2006-01-02T15:04:05`

Check the other formats to see the pattern
https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

For instance `RFC3339` is `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00`.

https://play.golang.org/p/ZHu6nbPtsJt